# Material Design Lite fixed tabs menu title not alignied?

Tags: html, css, navbar, material-design-lite

When trying to use the example of the menu layout with Fixed Tabs, with Googl'es MDL: http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout .

The "title", next to the hamburger menu, isnt aligned horizontally, like it is in the example.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple header with fixed tabs. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header
                mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="fixed-tab-1">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="fixed-tab-2">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="fixed-tab-3">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPaBzW

Comment: Do you have any demo to show? fiddle or somethin' ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPaBzW

It works fine there, but not when i put that into index.html on my computer then try to load it. The title isnt aligned with the hamburger.

Comment: it is working for me on local computer - using Chrome 47.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Would post pic of it if i could :P